# Using enum values in model stored in a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, enums

I don't seem to figure it out how to use enum values in an ASP.NET MVC 3 model (using code first approach) so that they are stored in a database and are preserved.

My model code looks like:

```
public class TestNews
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    //[EnumDataType(typeof(TestNewsType))]?
    public TestNewsType Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public enum TestNewsType : short
{
    Draft = 0,
    PublishedPublicly = 1,
    PublishedInternally = 2,
    Removed = 3
}
```

After the database gets recreated it contains the table TestNews, but it contains only the columns:

- Id
- Date
- Title

How to make it also store the Type in the database? And also should the EnumDataType annotation be used?

I would later like to use it in a controller action like:

```
    public ActionResult Latest(int count=5)
    {
        var model = db.TestNews
            .Where(n => n.Type == TestNewsType.PublishedPublicly)
            .OrderByDescending(n => n.Date)
            .Take(count)
            .ToList();
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [June CTP of Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-enums-june-ctp.aspx) introduced Enum support.

As an alternative to using the CTP, at the MSDN blogs is an article on [how to fake enums with Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/05/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4.aspx).